# I need to start a php with a htm button (ngninx)

Tags: php, linux, bash, ubuntu, nginx

nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu 20)

```
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Feb 24 2022 14:55:48) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I've created a simple page in html, for execute a script in php with a button.
Here my html:

```
<html>
        <head>
        </head>

        <body>
hello

                <form action="path-of-myphp.php" method="post">
                        <input type="submit" name="backupMySql" value="Backup"/>
                </form>

        </body>

</html>
```

and here my php

```
<?php
   echo "Hello";
?>
```

Here my nginx config

```
server {
    server_name  mysite.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://localhost:5003;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
     location ~ \.(php)$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }




    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = mysite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name  mysite.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I see correctly the button, but when i click on it, i am redirected to another url, and this url is [www.mysite.com/path-of-myphp.php](http://www.mysite.com/path-of-myphp.php)

[error nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8MbF.png)

I don't undestand why my nginx can't execute this simple php, meanwile by shell i can execute all..
Anyone have tips?
thank very much

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Are you sure this is in any way related to Bash, Ubuntu, or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

The nginx error is a 404 not found error and it means that nginx can't find your file.
Due to your nginx configuration your website root is in /var/www/html, so make sure that your php file is inside this directory:

```
/var/www/html/path-of-myphp.php
```

Please take a look also to the permissions of your php file. It has to be readable by www-data user

```
chown (your user or www-data):www-data /var/www/html/path-of-myphp.php
chmod 755 /var/www/html/path-of-myphp.php
```

In this way the www-data user has at least read and execution permissions by the group.